# why TreeSet 's remove() method doesn't work for Integers?

Tags: java, treeset

The code results this output --> [5, 4, 3], 
Why 4 is still in the set ?

```java
public class Temp4 {
    public static void main (String[] args)   { 
        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>( (I1,I2)->(I1 < I2) ? 1 : (I1 > I2) ? -1 :-1);

        set.add(new Integer(5) );
        set.add(new Integer(3) );              
        set.add(new Integer(4) );

        set.remove(new Integer(4)) ;

        System.out.println( set  );

    }
}
```

Comment: Your comparator is wrong. It should return 0 as default value. As is, no equality can found using your comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `Comparator` is broken, it should return `0` for equal elements.

Second the `TreeSet` uses `compare` to find elements,  in contradiction to the general `Set` contract.

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

Comment: I suggest to add some explanation to link between `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` as the question is asking about `TreeSet`.

Comment: But i have to use TreeSet so that it contains duplicates  also .

Comment: But a Set does never contain duplicates. If you need to handle duplicates,  consider a `List` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your comparator, you're not handling the cases in which the objects are equal (you should return 0). Anyway, in your case you don't even need to explicitly use a custom comparator, you can create your set like this and it will work:

```
TreeSet<Integer> set= new TreeSet<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder()) ;
```